# Qt - Remembering the last checked Radiobutton

Tags: c++, windows, qt, radio-button

I have 3 radio buttons and a spinbox. Each radio button is supposed to chnage the spinboxes value to inches, feet or meters respectively. How would i do that? I would have to know which radio button was active last, right? Could someone give me some example code please?

Answer (score 3):

Radio Button and check boxes hold their state as value, and expose it to your user. You can call [isChecked()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#checked-prop) to know the state of your member variable radio button. Something like

```
void some_button_hit(bool checked)
{
    if (inches.isChecked()) {...}
    else if (feet.isChecked()) {...}
    else if (meters.isChecked()) {...}
}
```

and 'wire' the event [toggled](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#toggled) from any of these. This is usually done in initialization,
using the form editor, or via connect.

Using the form editor, right click on a radio button, and follow goto slot...
The editor build and connect the event handler:

```
void GroupBox::on_feet_toggled(bool checked)
{
    ui->label->setText("feet");
}
void GroupBox::on_inches_toggled(bool checked)
{
    ui->label->setText("inches");
}
void GroupBox::on_meters_toggled(bool checked)
{
    ui->label->setText("meters");
}
```

Comment: You may consider mentioning `QSignalMapper` for good measure.

Comment: my QT it's a bit rusty...I remember connect wasn't very easy to work with. Maybe the OP should learn to put the form editor to good use...